# Advice on database design - SQL recipe editor

Tags: sql, database-design, recipe

I want to build an SQL-based recipe editor for a brewery. I have n recipes:

- Every recipe is part of a category.
- Every category has a list of steps.
- Steps can be reused in the same category several times and in different orders.
- Every step has n set-points.
- Setpoints change based on the recipe.
- The same steps used more than once in the same category could have different setpoints within the same recipe.

I have 3 recipes (BeerA, BeerB and BeerC):

- BeerA and BeerB are lager (category), while BeerC is a stout (category).
- Lager has 5 steps
  (start, fermentation, wait, fermentation, maturation).
- All the steps have 2 set-points
  (time, temperature).

BeerA specific set-points could be:

- Start:
  [10seconds, 30 degrees]
- Fermentation:
  [2 days, 27 degrees]
- Wait:
  [3 hours, 25 degrees]
- Fermentation:
  [3 days, 23 degrees]
- Maturation:
  [5 days, 3 degrees]

BeerB has the same steps, same order, but with different set-points. BeerC has only 3 steps. What would be an example of table design? I was thinking:

- Recipe table
  (RecipeID, RecipeName, categoryID).
- Category table
  (CategoryID, CategoryName).
- Steps table (I need the reference to the category and to the recipe).

How can I deal with steps using different set-points? I believe I need also a Setpoints table, but how to design it?

Comment: How many different kinds of possible set points are there?  If this list is small, then there’s a simpler way to do it.  Otherwise you have to abstract/pivot the recipe-setpoint relation.

Comment: For this specific project I would need only 2 setpoints for every step, for the next project it would be probably more about 10-15.No more than that

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) will give you an outline to follow when creating your database tables.

Comment: Do all lagers have the same five steps, just with different temp, time? Do all stouts have the same 3 steps, just with different temp, time?

Comment: @DamirSudarevic in this example yes. The number of steps or position in the recipe could be modified in the main editor but once the lager is defined/saved, the same procedure will be used for all the lager beers, with only different temp and time which will be defined in the Beer A or B recipe. In addition to that the same step in the lager recipe used twice (in my example fermentation) could have different temp, time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Beer category BCT exists.
--
category {BCT}
      PK {BCT}
```

```
-- Brewing step STP exists
--
step {STP}
  PK {STP}
```

```
-- Step sequence number ST# for brewing beer
-- of category BCT is step STP.
--
cat_step {BCT, ST#, STP}
      PK {BCT, ST#}

FK1 {BCT} REFERENCES category {BCT}
FK2 {STP} REFERENCES step     {STP}


-- Note: ST# in [1,2,3 ..]
```

```
-- Beer BER is of beer category BCT.
--
beer {BER, BCT}
  PK {BER}
  SK {BER, BCT}

FK {BCT} REFERENCES category {BCT}
```

```
-- Step sequence number ST# of recipe
-- for brewing beer BER of beer category BCT
-- is at temperature TMP deg, for TIM minutes.
--
recipe {BER, BCT, ST#, TIM, TMP}
    PK {BER, ST#}

FK1 {BER, BCT} REFERENCES beer     {BER, BCT}
FK2 {BCT, ST#} REFERENCES cat_step {BCT, ST#}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

```
Using suffix # to save on screen space.
OK for SQL Server and Oracle, for others use _NO.
For example, rename OPT# to OPT_NO.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is a reasonable starting point; I would have a "Beer" entity, to allow you to hold information about the beer, and I would also have some sort of versioning (or start/end dates) on the recipe - in case it ever changes.

So something like this (just an example, not meant to be a definitive model):
[image]